# How do I use my 'volume control' buttons which are located on the same buttons as the 4 and 5? I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop/notebook

Tags: toshiba-laptop

Yeah, just wondering how to use the volume control, I've tried holding down the shift button but that just gives me the dollar sign or the percentage sign, I'm not sure what else to do...

Please help, it's not so much urgent, but it's annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button in the corner and press them.